# Bootstrap Toggle - One is on, the other is off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

I'm using [this library](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) to implement toggle buttons. I have two toggle buttons. My purpose is when switching on one of them, the other should be switched off.

As the library instructs, I create two `input` elements:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" class="switch switch-on" checked value="true">
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" class="switch switch-off">
```

And my jQuery code to handle them:

```
$('.switch-on').change(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('switch-on');
    $(this).addClass('switch-off');
    $(this).bootstrapToggle();
});

$('.switch-off').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('switch-off');
    $(this).bootstrapToggle();
    $('.switch-on').click();
    $(this).addClass('switch-on');
});
```

I have tried many ways, including changing class names, triggering events, but totally in vain. The class names are not even changed when I inspect elements. Why isn't it working?

Comment: once check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/knvnx2ks/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this snippet,

```js
$("#toggle1").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#toggle2").bootstrapToggle('off');
  }
});
$("#toggle2").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#toggle1").bootstrapToggle('off');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" class="switch switch-on toggle" checked value="true" id="toggle1">
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" class="switch switch-off toggle" id="toggle2">
```